# How to limit memory usage .net core web site in kestrel hosting in IIS

Tags: iis, memory, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am using IIS hosting .net core web site. I have deliberately written in a way to consume all the server memory. How can I set up in a way so that if the dotnet process exceed a certain memory limit, it will recycle itself.

I cannot find any options in kestrel doing this. IIS won't have any effect as well since it is just a reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

The only method I can think of is using a powershell script to run overtime to monitor and kill the process, in WMI event subscription

$processToMonitor = 'Thunderbird.exe'
$threshold = 100MB

Register-WmiEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name='$processToMonitor' AND TargetInstance.WorkingSetSize > $threshold" -Action { Get-Process -PID $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.ProcessId | Stop-Process -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null }